# C++ STL containers of local objects' addresses

Tags: stl

What if I store pointers to stack objects in the container? Will this be also safe? Which destructor will be called first: List<> destructor, or (P1 and P2)? It is for sure that "delete" shouldn't be used here; since these are all stack objects, but is the compiler smart enough to avoid destructing the objects (&P1 and &P2)? P1 and P2 should be automatcally destructed when they go out of scope.

The code:

```
int main()
{
    list<MyPoint*> myList;
    MyPoint P1 = MyPoint(3,4);
    MyPoint P2 = MyPoint(1,2);

    myList.push_back(&P1);
    myList.push_back(&P2);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since destructors are called in the reverse order of object construction, `P2` and `P1` in your code will be destructed before `myList`.

Furthermore, the pointers stored in `myList` are not accessed during the destruction. Thus, it is safe even if you declare `P1` and `P2` earlier than `myList`.